# Why does IntelliJ tell me that my class never returns null?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
private void addCompoundsFrom(Verse verse) {
    Optional<List<Compound>> compounds = Optional.of(verse.getCompounds());
    if (compounds.isPresent()) {
        for (Compound compound : compounds.get()) {
            addCompoundsFrom(compound);
        }
    }
}
```

The IntelliJ inspector tells me that the if-statement is always true. How can it know that? This is the Compounds class:

```
public class Compounds extends PositionalIds {

    @XmlElement(name = "verse")
    private List<Verse> verses;

    public List<Verse> getVerses() {
        return verses;
    }
}


@XmlTransient
public abstract class PositionalIds {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "start")
    private String startId;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "end")
    private String endId;

    public String getStartId() {
        return startId;
    }

    public String getEndId() {
        return endId;
    }
}
```

And the Verse class:

```
public class Verse extends PositionalIds {

    @XmlElement(name = "compound")
    private List<Compound> compounds;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "notation")
    private String notation;

    public List<Compound> getCompounds() {
        return compounds;
    }

    public String getNotation() {
        return notation;
    }
}
```

If I stop using `Optional` to wrap the `verse.getCompounds()` result and instead just do a null check, the inspection message goes away.

I'm using Java 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Optional` class has two methods:

- `Optional.of` -> throws exception if the parameter is `null`
- `Optional.ofNullable` -> creates an empty optional if the parameter is `null`

Hence if your method returns null, the `of()` method will throw an exception and empty optional will never reach your `if` statement

Answer (score 2):

`Optional.of(verse.getCompounds());` returns an `Optional` that contains a valid value.

The `isPresent` check that follows will always be true because the `Optional` `compounds` will never not have a value, since you just set it to a valid value on the line above.

Comment: Ah, I think what I meant to use was `ofNullable`, instead of `of`

Comment: @Sahand Yes, that would make more sense.